# How can I keep a backup of my web application being developing live on web server?

Tags: codeigniter, github, backup, coda

I am using Coda to create a web application using CodeIgniter. I am hosting it live on hostgator and testing it as well. I want to know if there is a way to use some kind of Revision contorl or backup system like Github that would allow me to save my files and keep them updated without having to actually do the folder copy pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a remote repo at hostgator, and push changes to the remote using git, that doesn't require github, you can just do it from a repo locally on your machine.

[Here is a tutorial](http://web2.0goodies.com/blog/git/using-hostgator-as-a-remote-git-repository/).

Comment: Is it a feasible technique ebaxt?

Comment: Sure, it's how hosts like heroku let's you deploy your app. Having said that, heroku's setup is streamlined for this sort of thing...

Comment: I don't think heroku hosts plain PHP apps (they host facebook apps written in PHP tho.). What I meant was pushing to a production environment using Git is a feasible technique that is very useful and productive. I did a quick search for providers that support PHP and found http://pagodabox.com/, have a look. If that doesn't fit your need, I'm sure you can create some "homemade" solution.

Comment: thanks but il use a home made one dont know how to push to github while the files are already on a web host:S